# Android Emulator Keyboard

Tags: python, android, sl4a

I'm using the Android 2.2 SDK emulator to test out the Scripting Layer for Android and have one annoyance.

When you launch a Python interpreter and start to type code it appears that the parentheses key isn't mapped properly. When I hit the key on the PC keyboard I get ^[[20~ instead. What am I missing?

Comment: Pass the `-help-keys` option to the emulator and paste the output.

Comment: That shows the list of special keys but doesn't say anything about the "(" key.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Control-K button actually toggles the left-ALT key on the PC to mimic the virtual keyboard left-ALT.